# How badly does Goji berry spread?

Tags: berries, invasive

I've read [here](http://forums.gardenweb.com/discussions/1438142/can-goji-become-invasive) that goji berry spreads.

How badly does it spread?

Should I worry about it spreading?

Answer (score 1):

Whether it becomes invasive or not depends entirely on its growing conditions - if it likes them, then it will be highly invasive, if its not keen, not only will it not spread, it won't be too productive either. Here's some reading on the plant and the conditions it likes

http://www.pfaf.org/user/Plant.aspx?LatinName=Lycium+barbarum

Comment: According to pfaf "Suitable for: light (sandy), medium (loamy) and heavy (clay) soils, prefers well-drained soil and can grow in nutritionally poor soil. Suitable pH: acid, neutral and basic (alkaline) soils. It can grow in semi-shade (light woodland) or no shade."
So what conditions does it not like?

Comment: It's native to the area, but need to know where to find it, so i'm looking at ordering it.

Comment: @iAndelin - in poorly drained, heavy wet soil, particularly in shade, and in heavy shade. Grows really well in free draining but moist soil conditions, especially in sun,, when it will spread as far as it can.